# Gnome Classic loading instead of Gnome 3

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati, gnome

After updating ATI drivers my Gnome 3 interface is gone. Gnome classic is loading instead.

Ubuntu 11.10 Unity along with Gnome 3 (however Unity went missing from the selection menu on login screen). Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 3):

I am new to Ubuntu and I also had problem using Gnome 3 shell under ATI driver. But i found a [solution](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29) with AMD APP SDK Developer installation.

http://developer.amd.com/Downloads/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.6-lnx64.tgz

It is developer version but the difference from catalyst 11.11 & 11.12 is in fglrx. Its fglrx version is 8.93.10 while the others have 8.92. I no longer have any problem with Gnome 3 shell. But it adds an annoying "AMD Testing Use Only" logo to right bottom corner.

Hopefully it will fix all your gnome 3 problems....

Comment: The file doesn't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859626

There is a good solution where the default driver does not help.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` solved the same problem for me (I have Intel integrated GPU in my PC, but oddly some NVIDIA packages were installed with an update).